# Deploy to Azure with a reference to a project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure

I'm deploying PrjA to Azure WebSites (via Git), everything works fine if PrjA references PrjB.dll but doesn't work if PrjA reference the project PrjB. Azure says that it cannot find PrjB (correct, I do not want to push source code & C for PrjB).
When PrjA reference project PrjB I can read in properties of References/PrjB that Copy Local is set to true, so I thought it was working.

In other words, I'd like to reference project PrjB from PrjA so that I can hit F12 and get to the right source but I would like to push to the repo/Azure just the PrjB.dll not the entire project.

Is this possibile?